# How to write a dotted arrow?

Tags: arrows

How can I have a dotted arrow in LaTeX? I can have it in a diagram using tikzcd and "dotted" but I would like to have it also in the text, to replace $\dasharrow$.

Comment: You can use Ti*k*Z also in the text, which may be the simplest way since then the arrows would look the same. Please provide an MWE.

Comment: No dotted arrows in the comprehensive symbol list (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/?lang=en)

Comment: You might `\setbox` an arrow using Ti*k*Z in your preamble and write yourself a macro which inserts that box (could even spend a `\mathchoices` and resize it accordingly).

Comment: @Skillmon This seems good. Can I then have something which is the same size as $\dasharrow$ and which is dotted? Can you please give an answer with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along my comment, the following could be used. You could do the resizing stuff with Ti*k*Z, too, instead of using `graphicx`'s macros. I don't know which is faster, but guess it should be `graphicx` as Ti*k*Z tends to be slow.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newbox\dottedarrow@box
\setbox\dottedarrow@box\hbox
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[dotted,->] (0,0) -- (1.5em,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\newcommand*\dottedarrow
  {\relax\ifmmode\expandafter\dottedarrow@m\else\expandafter\dottedarrow@t\fi}
\newcommand*\dottedarrow@t[1][1.5em]
  {\resizebox{#1}{!}{\raisebox{.5ex}{\usebox\dottedarrow@box}}}
\newcommand*\dottedarrow@m[1][]
  {%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
      \mathchoice% values are trial and error based\ldots
        {\dottedarrow@t}
        {\dottedarrow@t}
        {\dottedarrow@t[1.1em]}
        {\dottedarrow@t[0.9em]}%
    \else
      \dottedarrow@t[#1]%
    \fi
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent
$\dasharrow\dottedarrow^{\dottedarrow\dasharrow^{\dottedarrow\dasharrow}}$\\
$\dottedarrow\dasharrow^{\dasharrow\dottedarrow^{\dasharrow\dottedarrow}}$\\
The \dottedarrow\ works in text, too.
\end{document}
```

[image]